# как определить ширину блока с контентом на любом сайте (для виджета)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Суть такова, есть самописный виджет, встраивается посредством `js` в `<head>`.
Если на сайте есть стандартный класс `container`, то все хорошо, а вот если нет, то элементы виджета могут смещаться по горизонтали.
Для небольшой наглядности (очень примерно):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуется чтоб граница всегда совпадала с границей контента, как можно вычислить данное дело?

Пробовал вычислять `width` первого `div` в `body`
`$('body > div').css("width");`
но там может оказаться все что угодно, хотелось бы универсальное и надежное решение.
Дали ссылку на кривой сайт, надо чтоб даже на нем нормально отображалось ([кривой сайт](http://uszn-pavlovo.mya5.ru/)).

Comment: это очень геморное дело. далеко не на всех сайтах такая верстка как в примере. Более того, на некоторых сайтах первый div может служить лишь обёрткой и меть всю ширину.

Comment: о том и речь. что первый div - не вариант смотреть и что верстка везде разная, по этому и хотелось бы узнать ширину именно контента на сайте, чтоб динамично задавать ширину виджету.

Comment: Один из вариантов это проходится по элементам после body и взять первый элемент у которого внутренняя ширина меньше чем ширина экрана, не учитывая padding и margin.

Comment: Мысль интересная, конечно не дает гарантий, но хоть что-то. Спасибо!